# Unable to resolve assets module metro bundle error in React Native app on Macbook M1

Tags: react-native, svg, compiler-errors, icons, metro-bundler

Launch React Native app on Macbook M1 with metro metro.config.js:

```
const {getDefaultConfig} = require("metro-config")

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: {sourceExts, assetExts},
  } = await getDefaultConfig()
  return {
    transformer: {
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: true,
        },
      }),
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"],
    },
  }
})()
```

My app structure:

```
Root
  |--app
      |--assets
      |    |--icons
      |
      |--components
              |--tab
                  |-tab.tsx
```

Import icon in tab.tsx file from assets folder like this:

```
import CloseIcon from "assets/icons/close-icon.svg"
```

Get the error:

> error: Error: Unable to resolve module assets/icons/close-icon.svg from root/app/components/tab/navigation/tab.tsx: assets/icons/close-icon.svg could not be found within the project or in these directories:
> node_modules
> ../../node_modules

And I tried to clear cache:
[image]

But it does not help me. And only one step to help me sometimes - close all apps and restart my laptop. And the error disappears for a while, but after appears again and again. Can you recommend me please how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error happens every day on Mac M1 in the project with absolute svg imports from react-native-svg-transformer, and only the one decision is to restart metro bundler with the next command:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```